# Mongodb partial matching

Tags: javascript, regex, mongodb, levenshtein-distance, fuzzy-search

How to get all documents in mongodb with one levenshtein distance.

I have collection for football teams.

```
{
    name: 'Real Madrir',
    nicknames: ['Real', 'Madrid', 'Real Madrir' ... ]
}
```

And user searched `Real Madid` of `Maddrid` or something else.

I want to return all documents that contains nicknames with 0 or 1 levenshtein distance to given search string.

I think there is two ways, mongodb full text search or regex.

So can I write such regex or query ?

Thank you.

Comment: Read this for more clues: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27977575/mongodb-approximate-string-matching

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For full-text search, first you must create a [Text Index](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/full-text-search-in-mongodb--cms-24835) on your `nicknames` field. Documents inserted before an index has been created will not be searchable. The search only works for documents that have been inserted *after* the index has been created. Then when you perform a search using MongoDb's `$text` and `$search` operators, MongoDb will return the documents whose `nicknames` field corresponds to the search text. For regex matching, MongoDb has a `$regex` operator you can use.

Here are a couple of short examples:

**Full Text Search**

1. Save this script as `football.js`. It will create a `teams` collection with a Text Index and two documents for us to search.

```js
// create football database
var db = connect("localhost:27017/football");

/* 
   note:
   You may also create indexes from your console
   using the MongoDb shell. Actually each of these
   statements may be run from the shell. I'm using
   a script file for convenience.
*/

// create Text Index on the 'nicknames' field 
// so full-text search works
db.teams.createIndex({"nicknames":"text"});

// insert two teams to search for
db.teams.insert({
    name: 'Real Madrir',
    nicknames: ['Real', 'Madrid', 'Real Madrir' ]
})

db.teams.insert({
    name: 'Fake Madrir',
    nicknames: ['Fake']
})
```

2. Open your terminal and navigate to the directory where you saved `football.js`, then run this script against your local MongoDb instance by typing `mongo football.js`.
3. Type `mongo` from your terminal to open the MongoDb Shell and switch to the `football` database by typing `use football`.
4. Once you're in the football database, search for one of your documents using `db.teams.find({"$text":{"$search":"<search-text>"}})`

```js
> use football

// find Real Madrir
> db.teams.find({"$text":{"$search":"Real"}})

// find Fake Madrir
> db.teams.find({"$text":{"$search":"Fake"}})
```

**Regex**

If you want to search using a regex, you will not need to create an index. Just search using mongodb's `$regex` operator:

```js
//find Real Madrir
db.teams.find({"nicknames": {"$regex": /Real/}})

db.teams.find({"nicknames": {"$regex": /Real Madrir/}})

//find Fake Madrir
db.teams.find({"nicknames": {"$regex": /Fa/}})

db.teams.find({"nicknames": {"$regex": /ke/}})
```

**Mongoose**

This is how each of these searches would work in NodeJS using [mongoose](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose):

```js
var searchText = "Madrir"; // or some value from request.body

var searchRegex = new RegExp(searchText);

var fullTextSearchOptions = {
  "$text":{
    "$search": searchText
  }
};

var regexSearchOptions = {
  "nicknames": {
    "$regex": searchRegex
  }
};

// full-text search
Team.find(fullTextSearchOptions, function(err, teams){

  if(err){
    // ...
  }else if(teams){
    // ...
  }

})

// regex search
Team.find(regexSearchOptions, function(err, teams){

  if(err){
    // ...
  }else if(teams){
    // ...
  }

})
```

Answer (score 1):

This is coming late, but hopefully, will aid someone else searching for this.

The only options are not to use regex (does not use indexes so, will be very slow for large datasets) or use the normal `$text` search (fast indexed searching but no partial matches). There is a third option that uses a bit more index memory, but both supports partial matches and uses indexes (so it's fast).

You create your own "index" by generating an array of strings from a string field (call that `name` for example) and storing the resulting array in an indexed array field (let's call that `_nameSearch`). Like so

```js
const getSearchArray: (str) => string[] = _str => {
  const str = _str.toLowerCase();
  const output = [];
  let acc = "";
  let accTotal = "";
  str.split("").forEach(char => {
    // Reset accumulator when space is encountered
    // Otherwise, add the new phrase to the array
    accTotal += char;
    output.push(accTotal);
    if (char === " ") {
      acc = "";
    } else {
      acc += char;
      output.push(acc);
    }
  });
  return Array.from(new Set(output));
};
```

So if the `name` value is "option", `_nameSearch` would be `["o", "op", "opt", "opti", "option"]` You can then, index `_nameSearch`. So you schema would look like this:

```js
const schema = new Schema(
  {
    name: String,
    _nameSearch: { type: [String], index: true },
    ...
  }
);
```

Querying the `name` field would be as easy as `db.collection.find({ _nameSearch: SEARCH_STRING })`. And you'd be able to find partial matches and also make use of indexes (so very fast searching). You will however make use of a bit larger index for the `name` field, so it's a trade-off, but a viable option to consider.