# how to find partial search in Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

How to find partial search?

Now Im trying to find

```
db.content.find({$text: {$search: "Customer london"}})
```

It finds all records matching `customer`, and all records matching `london`.

If I am searching for a part of a word for example `lond` or `custom`

```
db.content.find({$text: {$search: "lond"}})
```

It returns an empty result. How can I modify the query to get the same result like when I am searching for `london`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mongoDB prefix wildcard: fulltext-search ($text) find part with search-string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24343156/mongodb-prefix-wildcard-fulltext-search-text-find-part-with-search-string)

Comment: Could you take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69767176/12011575

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex to get around with it (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/). However, it will work for following :

if you have word **Cooking**, following queries may give you result

- cooking(exact matching)
- coo(part of the word)
- cooked(The word containing the english root of the document word, where cook is the root word from which cooking or cooked are derived)

If you would like to go one step further and get a result document containing **cooking** when you type **vooking** (missplled V instead of C), go for elasticsearch.

Elasticsearch is easy to setup, has extremely powerful edge-ngram analyzer which converts each words into smaller weightage words. Hence when you misspell, you will still get a document based on score elasticsearch gives to that document.

You can read about it here : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html

Comment: and what about if I search two words. I want to find all records which have each words or one of this words, for example Customer london

Answer (score 0):

it will always return the empty array for partial words like when you are searching for **lond** to get this type of text **london**..

Because it take full words and search same as that they are ..

Not achive same results like :-

**LO** **LON** **LOND** **LONDO** **LONDON**

Here you may get help from **ELASTIC-SEARCH**  . It is quite good for full text search when implement with mongoDB.

Refrence : [ElasticSearch](https://www.compose.com/articles/mongoosastic-the-power-of-mongodb-and-elasticsearch-together/)

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

The find all is to an Array
`clientDB.collection('details').find({}).toArray().then((docs)` =>

I now used the `str.StartWit`h in a for loop to pick out my record.

```
        if (docs[i].name.startsWith('U', 0)) {
          return console.log(docs[i].name);

        } else {
            console.log('Record not found!!!')
        };
```

This may not be efficient, but it works for now

Comment: This is not just inefficient, this is dangerously stupid. In a collection of hundreds of thousands of documents, this can take entire minutes to just query the db. Not to mention the amount of RAM needed for the db, and the amount of RAM needed for the server itself to process (potentially) entire MB of records. Don't do this.