# Text Indexes MongoDB, Minimum length of search string

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have created a text index for collection X from mongo shell

```
db.X.ensureIndex({name: 'text', cusines: 'text', 'address.city': 'text'})
```

now if a document whose name property has a value **seasons**, its length is 7

so if I run the find query(with a search string of length <= 5)

```
db.X.find({$text: {$search: 'seaso'}})
```

it does not return any value if I change the search string to **season** (length >= 6) then it returns the document.

Now my question is does the search string has some minimum length constraint to fetch the records.
if yes, then is there is any way to change it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MongoDB `$text` searches do not support partial matching. MongoDB allows support text search queries on string content with support for case insensitivity and **stemming**.

Looking at your examples:

```
// this returns nothing because there is no inferred association between 
// the value: 'seasons' and your input: 'seaso'
db.X.find({$text: {$search: 'seaso'}})

// this returns a match because 'season' is seen as a stem of 'seasons'
db.X.find({$text: {$search: 'season'}})
```

So, this is not an inssue with the length of your input. Searching on `seaso` returns no matches because:

- Your text index does not contain the whole word: `seaso`
- Your text index does not contain a whole word for which `seaso` is a recognised stem

This presumes that the language of your text index is English, You can confirm this by runing `db.X.getIndexes()` and you'll see this in the definition of your text index:

```
"default_language" : "english"
```

FWIW, if your index is case insensitive then the following will also return matches:

```
db.X.find({$text: {$search: 'SEaSON'}})
db.X.find({$text: {$search: 'SEASONs'}})
```

**Update 1:** in repsonse to this question *"is it possible to use RegExp"*.

Assuming the `name` attribute contains the value `seasons` and you are seaching with `seaso` then the following will match your document:

```
db.X.find({type: {$regex: /^seaso/}})
```

More details in [the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) but ...

- This will **not** use your text index so if you proceeed with using the `$regex` operator then you won't need the text index.
- Index coverage with the `$regex` operator is probably not what you expect, the brief summary is this: if your search value is anchored (i.e. `seaso`, rather than `easons`) then MongoDB can use an index but otherwise it cannot.

Comment: @AnkitKumar I have updated the answer to include an example showing use of `$regex`.

Comment: ok, then no need of text index, I'll use RegExp and $or operator to make it work on multiple props.