# MongoDB long response time for particular search query

Tags: mongodb

#### Case description:

- I have very simple application (generated by Spring Initializr) connected to mongo DB.
- Application task is to execute `2` queries (`count` and `find`) and return response. (mongo queries copied from [debug] logging in "MongoTemplate" that's why it shows `$regularExpression` rather than `$regex`)

The **query**:

```js
{
  "$and": [
    {"domain": "test"},
    {"deleted": {"$ne": true}},
    {"specialItem": {"$ne": true}},
    {"$or": [
        {"textSearch": {"$regularExpression": {"pattern": "\\QHANDLE\\E", "options": ""}}}
      ]
    },
    {
      "$or": [
        {"textSearch": {"$regularExpression": {"pattern": "\\QMOUNT\\E", "options": ""}}}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The **code** that generates aforementioned query:

```
@GetMapping("/demo") public ResponseEntity<String> demo() {
final List<org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria> criterias = new ArrayList<>();
    criterias.add(Criteria.where("domain").is("test"));
    criterias.add(Criteria.where("deleted").ne(true));
    criterias.add(Criteria.where("specialItem").ne(true));

    for (String word : List.of("handle", "mount")) {
        criterias.add(new Criteria().orOperator(
                Criteria.where("textSearch").regex("^.*" + Pattern.quote(word.toUpperCase()) + ".*")
        ));
    }

    final List<Criteria> orCriterias = new ArrayList<>();
    if(!orCriterias.isEmpty())
        criterias.add(new Criteria().orOperator(orCriterias));

    Query q = Query.query(new Criteria().andOperator(criterias.toArray(new Criteria[]{}))).with(Sort.by("domain", "deleted", "itemNumber"));
    q = q.skip(0).limit(20);
    long total = mongoOperations.count(q, DaoItem.class);
    final List<DaoItem> results = new ArrayList<>();
    List<DaoItem> daoItems = mongoOperations.find(q, DaoItem.class);

    results.addAll(daoItems);
    return ResponseEntity.ok("total: " + total + ", result: " + results); 
}
```

- `textSearch` is an array of string, f.e.: `["00000001", "SMOUNT.", "TER.", "YYY", "1", "GLASS"]`

---

#### Problem description:

Aforementioned **query takes long time** depending on the environment it's executed at.

---

#### Environments description:

- `mongo-java-driver|sync`, version: `4.7.1`
- `mongodb` version different per environment ("major" the same)
- `spring-boot` version: `3.1.3`

I used JMeter in a loop to have a basic response time graph printed for each environment. Test was done for the same domain: `test`, on every environment. For each non-local env. `ping <server address>` gives time `~160 ms`

I have four environments:

- Local,

  - **DB**: mongo (`v3.6.19`) on docker with `747259` documents to look through,
  - **Resources**: `m1 max` + `64 GB`,
  - **Space**: `530 GB` available of `2 TB`,
  - **Response time**: ~ `200` - `300` `ms`
- Dev,

  - **DB**: mongo installed on machine (`v3.6.8`) with `747259` documents to look through,
  - **Resources**: `Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2660 0 @ 2.20GHz` + `5,78 GB`,
  - **Space**: `/dev/sda1  146G  9.3G  129G   7% /`,
  - **Response time**: `3` - `8` `s`
- QA,

  - **DB**: mongo (`v3.6.8`) installed on machine with `42491` documents to look through,
  - **Resources**: `Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2660 0 @ 2.20GHz` + `5,78 GB`,
  - **Space**:  `/dev/sda1       146G  6.3G  132G   5% /`
  - **Response time**: ~ `2` - `3` `s`.

---

#### My observations:

- I set up a fresh mongodb instance on one of the remote servers
  (docker). Exported documents from "Dev" and imported in there. No one
  uses that database. When I connected to it, I've got response time
  similar to "Dev" env.
- As partial matching is used in a query, index cannot be used. The winning plan is: `IXSCAN` (without `textSearch` of course)
- Partial matching is required, hence I cannot use mongo `text` index.
- MongoDB config on each environment is the same (default)
- Query `explain` for `Dev` environment returns:

> ```
> Documents Returned: 138
> Index Keys Examined: 62448
> Documents Examined: 62446
> Actual Query Execution Time (ms): 2479
> Sorted in Memory: no
> Query used the following index: DOMAIN, DELETED SPECIALITEM
> ```

I changed the code, to generate following queries, and no change in response time was spotted:

```js
{
  "$and": [
    {"domain": "test"},
    {"deleted": {"$ne": true}},
    {"specialItem": {"$ne": true}},
    {"$or": [
        {"searchWords": {"$regularExpression": {"pattern": "\\QHANDLE\\E","options": ""}}},
        {"searchWords": {"$regularExpression": {"pattern": "\\QMOUNT\\E","options": ""}}}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

```js
{
  "$and": [
    {"domain": "test"},
    {"deleted": {"$ne": true}},
    {"specialItem": {"$ne": true}},
    {"searchWords": {"$regularExpression": {"pattern": "\\QHANDLE\\E","options": ""}}},
    {"searchWords": {"$regularExpression": {"pattern": "\\QMOUNT\\E","options": ""}}}
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is the `explain` result:

Query:

```js
{
    "domain": "test",
    "deleted": {"$ne": true},
    "specialItem": {"$ne": true},
    "searchWords": {"$regex": "(HANDLE|MOUNT)"}
}
```

`explain` result (short):

```js
Documents Returned: 2853 Index Keys Examined: 76606 Documents Examined: 76606 Actual Query Execution Time (ms): 1391 Sorted in Memory: no Query used the following index: DOMAIN ITEMNO
--- 
FETCH nReturned: 2853 Execution Time: 974ms IXSCAN nReturned: 76606 Execution Time: 358ms Index Name: domain_-1_itemNo_-1 Multi Key Index: no
```

---

#### My question

- I am a beginner when it comes to mongo, so I run out of options.
- What other direction I could go when it comes to that query, to debug why it's taking so long on "Dev" environment?
- I'm considering moving search mechanism to elasticsearch, but still, that particular question is about mongo, what I could do to reduce the response time to `~2s` f.e. on the `Dev` env?

Comment: Is it possible to upgrade to a supported version of MongoDB? MongoDB version 3.6.8 is about 4 years old and over 25,000 commits behind the most recent release. I'm not sure if anyone can confidently suggest improvements to your queries with such an old version.

Comment: @rickhg12hs if it would help, I think it is possible, for sure. As I'm looking for any solution, I setup latest mongo on docker, imported all `747k+` documents and I'm ready for any suggestions (right now, the response time is the same, around `9s`)

Comment: Would you review the query in your question?  It's curious that `"$or"` has single elements.

Comment: I have been playing with the query and I haven't spotted any significant changes (I edited the question and posted what queries I was generating). Is it possible, that becuase of the `textSearch` column/field are very long and there is 700k+ documents to look through it just has to take long ? maybe that's just how it is. If I wanted to speed up the search I should use elastic or solr. I'm just thinking that it's not mongo's fault, but fault of using regexp partial matching against to large set of documents

Comment: What are the functional and performance characteristics of a query like: `{"domain": "egtest-adbegt0000", "deleted": {"$ne": true}, "supplyArticle": {"$ne": true}, "searchWords": {"$regex": "(GIPS|Q1200)"}}`?

Comment: Added to "MyObservations" under "Here is the explain result:". I hope that is what you meant when you said "functional and performance characteristics".

Comment: That's good info.  What I actually meant was somewhat less detailed. _Functional:_ Did the query return the desired documents?  _Performance:_ How fast did the query execute?

Comment: With the primary query it returns: `138` documents. In your query, `2853` (probably because there is no 'match every character', `.*`). I found it quick fast though. One thing I don't understand is why response time in the app is around `8s` but, query response time is about `3s`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To optimize a query execution time, it's important to know your data schema, access pattern and available indexes.

The query execution plan you've provided shows that the only used index is the one on fields `domain` and `articleNo`. Is there other indexes in that collection?

I'd recommend you to create a [compound index](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/indexes/index-types/index-compound/) on `domain`, `deleted`, `specialItem` (the order is important):

```js
db.daoArticles.createIndex({
  domain: 1,
  deleted: 1,
  specialItem: 1,
})
```

If you don't query for `deleted`/`specialItem` in each `domain`, the index size can be reduced using [partial indexes](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-partial/), like:

```js
db.daoArticles.createIndex(
  { domain: 1 },
  { partialFilterExpression: { deleted: false, specialItem: false } }
)
```

> This query assumes that `deleted` and `specialItem` are strictly boolean fields, *i.e.* only contains `true` or `false` and no other values (btw, I don't know why you've used `{ deleted: { $ne: true } }` instead of `{ deleted: false }`)

HOWEVER... if the document count returned by the filter `{ deleted: false, specialItem: false }` is still large for each `domain`, I don't see other approach to reduce your query execution time (besides removing the partial text match).

As you said, [`text` indexes doesn't support partial match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46288227/can-a-text-search-perform-a-partial-match). So, unfortunately, we cannot use it in this case.

Last consideration: do you really need a partial text match? what are your use case?

Comment: there was an index with "domain"/"deleted"/"specialItem" along with the index for "domain"/"articleNo". Mongo used both in exchange, depending on certain circumstences (not sure which when). Both regular and partial indexes have to examine `62446` documents so just like you said I have to think about change in the solution itself as with all of them (even partial and I see that it was used) I have response time around `3` to `4` seconds. I will do something (f.e. try to getting rid of) with partial matching.